# Which takes precedence: /etc/hosts.allow or firewalld?

Tags: rhel, firewall, firewalld, tcp-wrappers

On a RHEL 7 server, `/etc/hosts.allow` has a number of IP addresses with full access.  The firewall (confirmed with `firewall-cmd`), there are no specific sources defined, and the default zone allows certain ports and services.
Which takes precedence?  Or for a specific example, if an IP address listed in `/etc/hosts.allow` tries to connect to the server using a port/service not allowed by the firewall rules, could it connect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no.

Neither between the TCP Wrapper system and the firewall settings takes precedence; rather, they work as layers.

`/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` are the host access control files used by the TCP Wrapper system. Each file contains zero or more *daemon:client* lines. The first matching line is considered.
Access is granted when a *daemon:client* pair matches an entry in `/etc/hosts.allow`. Otherwise, access is denied when a *daemon:client* pair matches an entry in `/etc/hosts.deny`. Otherwise, access is granted.

Now, if a service has been given access via the TCP Wrapper, but not on the firewall (and the firewall has a "deny all" rule by default, as it should be), the service won't be able to connect to the machine.

I haven't seen much TCP Wrappers configured nowadays -- you can avoid this system, which provides only basic filtering via libwrap, and use just `firewalld` to allow access to services. It's easier to configure and manage, and more powerful.